# Runtime Error 1004: Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I recorded this macro to update the date range of 16 charts. But, as you can see I am getting a Run-time error.

I have looked at other threads on stackoverflow that relate to this but none come close. The darn help button on excel doesn't help either.  Can you please advise? Here is the code:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 18").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 18").Activate
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")
    .PivotItems("Sep-15").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("Aug-14").Visible = True
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some simple code that should get you close.  You will need to change "MySheet" in this code to the name of the sheet containing the pivot table in your workbook, and your Date field must truly be text formatted in the "Mmm-YY" format.

```
Sub ShowThirteenDatesStartingLastMonth()
    Sheets("MySheet").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh

    Dim Dt As String

    With Sheets("MySheet").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")        
    For h = 1 To .PivotItems.Count - 1
        On Error Resume Next
        .PivotItems(h).Visible = False
    Next h

    For i = 1 To 13
        On Error Resume Next
        Dt = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - i, 1), "Mmm-YY")
        .PivotItems(Dt).Visible = True
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ayyzad, I would sure love to know if this solution works for you.  Based on the limited information I have about your scenario, I think it will.  I'm assuming that you have a basic pivot table with some kind of list on the left and these dates across the top, and that these dates are text fields essentially representing some form of data per month-year for each item in the list.  I set my own pivot table up this way and tested it out, and it works great.  (I actually learned something in the process!)

Comment: Also, I would like to suggest a potential change to the way your data is set up, if it is set up the way I'm imagining it with text date fields.  Depending on how you want your dates to sort in the pivot output, (whether you want the 2 duplicated months, in this case Sep-14 and Sep-15 appearing side by side or you want them sorted as if they were actual dates), it would make more sense to use an actual date format set to the 1st of each month or an all numeric text format that starts with the year instead of the month. Of course that would require changes to the code, but I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly Thank you. When I run it the information all updates and so does the chart The first time I ran it, it went from aug-14 aug-15, to sept 14- sept-15. Just the way we wanted! But when I run it again the data changes but this time the dates stay at sept 14 -sept-15. DId you get this issue as well?

Comment: Since I don't have your workbook, I can't be sure what exactly is happening, but my test was on a very simple data set and it worked perfectly for me. What do you mean by "the data changes"?  Does the position of data change (common in a pivot table), or do the actual values change?  If the values are changing in the pivot table, then they have to be changing in the source data.  I would need to see your workbook before I can lend any real insight into this.  Anyway, if my answer helped you, please mark it as an answer and vote it up if you can.

Comment: The data changes, meaning the pivot chart updates to the next trailing 13 month data..but the actual dates on the x axis stay at sept-'14 thru sept '15.

Comment: What are the dates on the x axis supposed to be at?  This code would be setting them up to be looking at the months previous of the current date, so according to the code, Sep-14 through Sep-15 is correct.  If they're supposed to be something else, then the code will need to change.

Comment: What needs to be tweaked if i need it to say Aug-'14 - Aug -'15 this month instead?

Comment: The determination for which months to make visible is made in this code:           Dt = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - i, 1), "Mmm-YY")              , where "- i" is subtracting a number of months from the current month counting from 1 to 13 in a loop.  So if you want this system to still show 13 months but you want it to move that group of months backward or forward by a number of months, you just add or subtract whatever number of months you want to change to the "- i" portion; in this case, you would want "- i - 1" to show Aug-14 - Aug-15.

Comment: I was getting the same error, but it was because I want to use my macro on more than one pivot table in my workbook.  When I recorded the macro, it put in "PivotTable1" as the name, which of course didn't match the names of the other PT's.  I modified the code to get the current PT name with "ActiveCell.PivotTable.Name", replaced the "PivotTable1" in the recorded macro with the variable.  Now it works without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without an example of your workbook, but I would try naming the sheet rather than using "activesheet".  It's also typically a bad idea to activate or select anything, and instead you should allow the code to do as much work as it can without selecting anything.
Something like this might work better:

```
With Sheets("MySheet").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")
.PivotItems("Sep-15").Visible = False
.PivotItems("Aug-14").Visible = True
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much Josh. Would you be so kind as to answer a follow up question?

Comment: Is there a way, maybe using and IF statement, to makes those dates change automatically? Every time I run this code I'd like the code to change the dates to move forward one month. So, right now it goes from Aug 14-Aug 15. Id like to make it so that it goes from sept 14 - Sept 15...is this possible? If so, can you please advise?

Comment: If the values exist in a pivot table and they actually need to be changed, then they need to be changed in the data the pivot table is referencing, not in the pivot table itself.  It's starting to sound like maybe a pivot table isn't the right solution for what you're trying to do, but I'm not really sure what it is you're trying to accomplish here.  If you're not trying to actually change the data, and just display different data within the pivot table, then you may have already been on the right track.

Comment: How much data are we talking about here?  If it's not more than about 30,000 rows, you may be able to rid yourself of some of the limitations of pivot tables by using a collection of match and indirect formulas to compile the same data and layout as the pivot table does, but with the dynamic flexibility you might be looking for.

Comment: What is that date format?  Is that "Mmm d" or "Mmm yy"? (Are you trying to change the data being displayed from: August 2014 - August 2015 to September 2014 - September 2015, or are you trying to change the data being displayed from August 14th - August 15th to September 14th - September 15th?

Comment: It's M yy. I'm trying to change from August 2014 - August 2015 to September 2014 - September 2015. So each time I run it I need to  move to the next month..i.e. Sep 2014- Sep 2015 then Oct 2014 - Oct 2015, then Nov 2014- Nov 2015, so on and so fourth.

Comment: Right now I have to go in and manually change those dates that are in parentheses, to the dates I need to show.

Comment: What criteria do you use to determine which date range you want to look at each time?  Whatever that criteria is, it can probably be coded into your macro.  As in, is it the month previous of the current month; in which case you can use some date functions to put together a text string that represents those dates in your pivot table, assuming they are text strings and not actually formatted dates.  If they are, it's even easier.

Comment: I'm usiong that .PivotItems, it is referring to the sort and filter option on the pivotchart. If we could just get that sort/filter option to automatically update to the next 13 trailing months.

Comment: Do the titles in your recorded macro "Sep-15" and "Aug-15" refer to whole date ranges, or single dates?  I.e., are the displayed values under these headers in a single column or multiple columns?  If you're trying to show/hide 13 pivot fields, then you'll need more code lines for that; 1 for each date.  Also, is the data the pivot table is referring to variable (can it possibly exclude any of the 13 dates at any time?)

Answer (score 0):

As Josh said, you should reference the exact sheet name and maybe even the exact Pivot table name.

Also, you should avoid using `.Select` and instead declare a variable for each pivot chart, for example.